# load testing by keep increasing the number of concurrent users

Tags: performance, load, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have 500 users in my csv file. I am doing load testing using jmeter. I want to run the script for first 100 hundred users. Once the execution for 100 concurrent user/Threads is done then I want to automatically increase the size of concurrent users to 200 and so on.

How I can achieve this ??

Comment: Try stepping thread group plugin. http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to set throughput according to your test scenario. Despite its name it doesn't have to be "constant", you can put a variable into "Target Throughput" input so you'll be able to modify concurrency on the fly.

Another option which could be easier / more flexible is [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

[image: Throughput Shaping Timer]